# Predict peaks within a time series

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, python, forecasting

I'm looking for a different approach to linear regression, but I don't know how to model and implement my data. I would like to predict spikes in CPU consumption in a time series using [LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn) or [newelm](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newelm.html). Something like, but with histograms colored by the peak intensity:

[image]

However I would like to divide my test data into parts due to using a high frequency in the interval (minutes), something like:

> trainA = interval 15min
>   trainB = interval 30min
>   trainC = interval 45min
>   trainD = interval 60min

A visual example of the original data would be something like:

[image]

And the tests are performed on these pieces of the data set, something like:

> trainA ---> trainC
>   trainB ---> trainD
>   trainA ---> trainD
>   trainB ---> trainA
>
> and so on...

I am a beginner in the world of data and forecasting, I would like suggestions on how to do this, if it is feasible to do so, what would be the best way and some examples of code.

A visual example of what the exit would be:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [A list of posts on peak detection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=peak++detec*)

Comment: I see some examples, but I confess that I am lost in relation to this approach, I never did anything like that, I need more solid instructions